# How do you add a recipient to a mail from outlook address book when contact does not have a name?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, address-book

Here is an image of me trying to add a contact to the current mail

[image: Addess book image]

As you can see outlook 2013 just adds the ; separator but not the email address.
When I add a display name I can add the recipient, but not before then.

Is there a setting to allow me to add that contact to the 'to' field just by email address?

I would prefer not having to export fix in excel and re-import.

**EDIT**

I tried to export and import, however these contacts does not export as if they do not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my knowledge, Outlook uses the Display Name column when we select recipients from the Address book.

In your situation, I'd like to suggest trying the following steps to fill the display name field in Excel:

1. Export the contacts folder as a .csv file, only keep the two columns below when mapping custom fields:
   [E-mail address and E-mail Display Name column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLpx9.png)
2. Let's say the email address is in column A, E-mail Display Name in column B, type "=A2" in cell B2, drag and drop to fill the remaining cells in column B:
   [fill the E-mail Display Name field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVBjh.png)
3. Save the csv file, import back to Outlook.

Comment: I was hoping not to export it to excel as mentioned by the question. This computer is a director's laptop that I reinstalled windows. I have limited time with the laptop and would like to complete it in one sitting, and have a solution when this happens again. One of the risks of export and import is duplicate or missing contacts which is a problem I would not like to explain to a director.